# Installation problems on my hp pavilion g7 1303

Tags: wubi

I just tried to install ubuntu using wubi (12.04.01). I restarted and I got that "no wubildr" stuff and then black screen and nothing happens. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

After "no wubildr error" wait for a minute it will boot up. 
To fix that just copy wubildr files directly to c:/.

If this doesn't work try this: go to `c:/ubuntu/winboot` (from Ubuntu File System `/host/ubuntu/winboot`) and copy all of its content.

Next step is to past all of the content to System Reserved. You can easly access it from Ubuntu, but from Windows you can use this Open Hidden System Drive: http://www.coderforlife.com/projects/win7boot/extras/#OpenHiddenSystemDrive
(Tried it myself, works)

Then just paste copied content from winboot and restart your PC.

The "no wubildr" error should be gone.

Comment: they are already in C:/

Comment: it doesnt boot. And they were already in C:/

Comment: Try these steps above in the answer.